# Probability distribution, finding Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a quick question.
If
$$
P(X=n)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
and I want to find CDF should I start with $n=0$? I think that then this probability is going to be closer to $0$, and if $n<0$ then the limit would be $1$. I don't know nice way of writing this formally though.

Comment: What is $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ ? what can you conclude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pmf is the following

$$\mathbb{P}[X=n]=\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

We immediately recognize a Geometric distribution counting the failures before the first success, thus the support is $n \in\{0;1;2;...\}$

The CDF is the following

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq n]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x=0}^n\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^x=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1-\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1-\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^{n+1}$$